# Viewing the table contents created in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android. I have created an application in android which stores data in sqlite database. I want to view those table data by giving select * from tablename and so I have downloaded the sqlite database browser. I am trying to open the database from the sqlite browser but I am getting errors. Could you please tell us what databse file should we need to open from the source code to get the database into sqlite browser.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a browser which will be as part of the eclipse environment follow this link and it might help you http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/questoid-sqlite-browser